# Fourier-Bessel Series for $f(x)=1-x$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, bessel-functions

I am trying to find the Fourier-Bessel series for the function $$f(x)=1-x\ \ \text{for} \ \ 0<x<1.$$

The Fourier-Bessel series has the form $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_nJ_v(k_nx), \ \ 0<x<l, \ \ \text{where} \ \ A_n=\frac{2}{J_{v+1}(k_n)^2}\int_{0}^{1} (1-x)J_v(k_nx)x \ dx.$$
I have tried to solve $A_n$ as follows.
\begin{align}
A_n=\frac{2}{J_{v+1}(k_n)^2}\int_{0}^{1}xJ_v(k_nx) \ dx-\frac{2}{J_{v+1}(k_n)^2}\int_{0}^{1} x^2J_v(k_nx) \ dx..
\end{align}
but I am bit unsure of how to proceed, as I do not know what the value of $v$ is. I know somewhere I will need to use the identity $$(k_nx)^vJ_v(k_nx)=\int (k_nx)^vJ_{v-1}(k_nx) \ dx,$$ but I am a little bit stuck.

Many thanks kind people (I am new to this site)

Comment: I highly recommend using an integral table book for those two. They're known integrals, but they might be a pain to establish yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: The Table of Integrals, Series, and Products I think is the name of the most often used resource.

Comment: Your last equation is wrong by a factor of $k_n$ (from change of variables).

Comment: Thank you for spotting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fourier-Bessel transform originates from a 2D transform, where you need two indices and $v$ enumerates the angular part. If your problem is part of a 2D problem, then you get the answer there. Otherwise, consider this: Bessel functions $J_v$ behave as $r^v$ around the origin, so $v=0$ is the only one that is capable of describing nonzero value at $r=0$ smoothly. If you do this for $v=1$ or higher, it will develop your function into something that has a discontinuous jump at the origin (similar to what happens if you expand a nonzero constant value into a *sine* series: you get a square wave).

So, every $v$ will describe a different orthogonal basis, but with different boundary condition at the origin, so $v=0$ is a natural choice for you.

Comment: Thank you a lot sir. However, I am stuck at this point $$\frac{2}{k_nJ_1(k_n)^2}\int_{0}^{1} (k_nx)J_1(k_nx) \ dx.$$

Comment: Are you able to solve this? It seems unsolvable without an integral table

Comment: These integrals do not have a closed form unless you count special functions. However, if you are using $J_0$ series (which makes sense as your function is nonzero at the origin), it *is* solvable, because $\int_0^1 kx J_0 (kx)dx=J_1(k)$.